Android studio install apk bundle fails
I have an android studio gradle project that uses the ndk and an asset pack.
When trying to run Run -> Debug 'app':
When my debug configuration is set to Deploy: Default APK, the apk installs.
When I set it to Deploy: APK from app bundle, I'm given the error:
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS Installation failed due to: 'Error code: 'INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS', message='INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113'' List of apks: [0] 'D:\core\config\android\gradle_build\app\build\intermediates\extracted_apks\debug\extractApksFromBundleForDebug\asset_pack-master.apk' [1] 'D:\core\config\android\gradle_build\app\build\intermediates\extracted_apks\debug\extractApksFromBundleForDebug\base-arm64_v8a.apk' [2] 'D:\core\config\android\gradle_build\app\build\intermediates\extracted_apks\debug\extractApksFromBundleForDebug\base-ja.apk' [3] 'D:\core\config\android\gradle_build\app\build\intermediates\extracted_apks\debug\extractApksFromBundleForDebug\base-master_2.apk' [4] 'D:\core\config\android\gradle_build\app\build\intermediates\extracted_apks\debug\extractApksFromBundleForDebug\base-xxhdpi.apk'

does anyone have expertise why this could happen?

You are trying to install an arm64_v8a build. INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS means the the device doesn't support arm64_v8a. Do you use an emulator (-> which emulator image is used?) or a physical device?
